# How to debug a flow as a specific user?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow, which when ran as the System Admin, works perfectly.

When I run it as a non admin, it doesn't and I get:

> An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
> An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information.

I have ticked Flow User on the user, and also ticked Run Flows on the profile

They have Modify All on all custom objects and Delete on standard objects

Ideally I want to debug this as the user to see what's going wrong, but I don't have the option to when logged in as them, and can't see a way to do this while logged in as Admin

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions experienced by users are sent by email to a designated administrator. You can control this setting in [Process Automation Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_troubleshoot_error_email.htm&type=5) in the Setup screen. There's no need to enable debug logs or anything else, as flows/processes do this automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

The above suggestions are useful. In addition, you can also customize your flow to handle exceptions to debug runtime state. Please refer to below article:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_build_logic_fault.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

Look up the User's ID and then go into your flow builder. Run the [flow in Debug](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_debug.htm) mode as the user (using their ID as an input).

This should allow you to iterate through the flow to narrow down the issue in real time.

Answer (score 0):

The fields which you are updating using flow, may not have edit access for the profile who is using the flow. Give them edit access for the fields at profile level.